# There is no AudienceManager in Microsoft.Office.Server Namespace

Tags: sharepoint-server, audiences

I could not find the AudienceManager Class in the Microsoft.Office.Server Namespace. Do I have to add any other namespace or am I dealing with any other problems? Please help.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudienceManager class is in below DLL. Ref [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audiencemanager.aspx)

Namespace:  Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience

Assembly:  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles (in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll)